# Showing custom error messages in django model form with bootstrap

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show custom error messages, if some field is not valid. I have following model:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)


class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = '__all__'
        error_messages = {
            'name': {
                'max_length': ("This user's name is too long."),
            },
        }
```

The view is:

```
def test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print "The form is submitted successfully."
        form = TestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print request.POST.get("name")
            return render(request, 'test.html',{'form' : TestForm()})
        else:
            print "Something wrong with inputs."
            return render(request, 'test.html',{'form' : form})
    else:
        return render(request,'test.html',{'form' : TestForm()})
```

and template is:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}
Test Form
{% endblock title %}  

{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block body_block %}
<h1>hello from test</h1>    

<form class='form-horizontal' role='form' action="." method="POST">
    <div class='form-group'>

        <label class='control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-2' for='id_name'>Name</label>
        <div class='col-md-6'>

            {% render_field form.name class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" %}
            {{ form.name.error_messages }} 
            {# I want to add here classes for alert-error etc #}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class='form-group'>
        <div class='col-md-offset-4 col-md-6'>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>


</form>    
{% endblock body_block %}
```

But, I am not getting any messages in the template. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `form.name.error_messages` to `form.name.errors` in your template.

It seems you render fields/errors one by one manually, explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually):

You may want to consider a more automatic approach using a [`{% for %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields) template tag.

**EDIT:** To change the default error message, you need to update your `error_messages` in the form `Meta` and overwrite the key used by django, in this case it is key `invalid`, based on [`IntegerField`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/218175b09d244b9c7c84c2f2d5f478297251bbe9/django/forms/fields.py#L250) source:

```
class Meta:
    model = Test
    fields = '__all__'
    error_messages = {
        'some_integer_field': {
            'invalid': 'some custom invalid message',
        },
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked. Can you please tell me how to override the default messages, e.g., for type error like int to char, I am getting: Enter a whole number? How can I override this?

Comment: Cool! Updated my answer to include this info.

Comment: I know but I want to override the message I got.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't clear what I meant, I added an example.